# How to replace front windscreen spray nozzle on toyota yaris

Tags: toyota, windshield-wipers, yaris

The adjusting end (ball) fell off, and this results in a weak spray stream. I found the part that matches my vehicle on eBay. But, I'm not sure how I would go about replacing it, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to detach it from the arm.

I have a 2013 Toyota Yaris XP13M (NHP13 Variant), with a single front windscreen wiper arm.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search for replacement procedures returns one Yaris forum.  https://www.yarisworld.com/forums/showthread.php?t=63111

Comment: Are you implying that I should take off the wiper arm to take off the spray nozzle?

Comment: Unless the spray nozzle is a separate part that's snapped on and off for replacement by itself, the entire wiper assembly may have  be removed to see if a mounting screw is holding the spray attachment.  Disconnect the rubber hose and check for a snap tab or mounting screw. Your replacement spray nozzle should give you an idea.